# Using a query to supply an Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, view, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I have a Microsoft Access form that is being supplied (somehow) by a query. The query contains three tables linked together via their respective primary and foreign keys, and the form displays data quite happily.

The strange thing (as far as I'm concerned) is the ability of the form to then allow data entry using the query.

However, if the user creates a new record, the whole thing seems to have problems due to a required field in the `[table2]` table.

```sql
SELECT [table1].*
    ,[table2].JobNo
    ,[table2].PlannedDateOC
    ,[table3].DateJobStarted
    ,[table1].PlanNo
FROM (
    [table1] LEFT JOIN [table2] ON [table1].PlanNo = [table2].PlanNo
    )
LEFT JOIN [table3] ON [table2].JobNo = [table3].JobNo
ORDER BY [table2].PlannedDateOC
    ,[table1].PlanNo;
```

According to the users, this form worked perfectly prior to conversion from Access 97/2003 format to Access 2010 (2007 file format).

Could anyone clarify whether this (the fact that it should work) is legitimate, and if this process would work in either version of Access, if so? The concept of being able to use a query for data entry is quite alien to me.

Let me know if you need further clarification.

**NOTE:**
One thing of note, here, is that I did move some of the fields into the form header so that they were always visible as the rest of the form scrolls. I don't know if this will have any side effects on the performance of the form.

Comment: above query will allow you to insert data into [table1] when all not null fields have values! what sort of problem do you have?

Comment: Thanks for responding, @krishKM. Quote: *However, if the user creates a new record, the whole thing seems to have problems due to a required field in the `[table2]` table.*  Basically the record won't save because there's a mandatory field in the second table.

Comment: and make sure only table1.fields are getting dirty when new record is inserted. Not all visible fields from other table.. that would be an(inconsistent update/insert) and will most probably result to an error

Comment: @krishKM: LOL! If only it were that simple! The project was written by a doctor *(if only we were allowed to do brain surgery)* who had a book about Ms Access ... should I continue?! So, there's reams of functionality in there, some of which I'm afraid to touch. Unfortunately, this is such a form. It appears that some of the data comes from the other tables (as you can see from the query). If what you say is true, then, it could be that the user is filling in one of these fields. I'll check that out, and if it's true, put an answer in and I'll mark you up as correct.

Comment: sure! let us know. (ideally just lock/disable the other fields from other tables) so they can still view them when opening for viewing)

Comment: @krishKM: Yep - that's what I had in mind.

Comment: there is no change in how the database engine and forms work in regards to the 20 year old version of access 97 vs the new 2016 version. So whatever the issue is - it not some change in how Access works - something else was/is messed up.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal: Thanks for your input, Albert. It is an obvious question that I had to ask.

Comment: @krishKM: Please post your comment as an answer and I'll give you the credit. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above query will allow you to insert data into [table1] when all *not null fields* have their values and make sure **only table1.fields** are getting dirty when new record is inserted.